# How to hide navbar in login or signup page reactn router

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I am using react-router v4 I am creating SPA using that so my navigation menu comes in all page but I don't want it to appear in my login or sign up page.
is there anyway to do it?I used localStorage but due to that it remains hidden always

below in my route

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter basename="/sephoraweb">
      <div>
        <HeaderContainer />


        <Route exact path="/" component={LoginContainer} hideNavBar={true} />
        <Route path="/signUp" component={SignUpContainer} />

      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
 </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and below is my navbar code

```
 render() {
    if (!this.props.programList) {
      return <Spinner name="circle" />;
    }
    if(!localStorage.getItem("token") || localStorage.getItem("token") == undefined)
       return null;
    const programValues = this.props.programList;

    return <NavBar programs={programValues} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `MainLayout` component's constructor do this.

```
constructor () {
  this.state = {
    isNavbarHidden: false
  };
}
```

In your componentDidMount for that component where you want to hide something

```
componentDidMount () {
  const currentRoute = this.props.location;
  if (currentRoute === 'YOUR_ROUTE_NAME') {
    this.setState({ isNavbarHidden: true });
  }
} // end of componentDidMount
```

`this.props.location` is a method of `react router` which tells you the current path on which the user is at the moment.

Now in your render() method do something like this

```
render () {
    const { isNavbarHidden } = this.state;
    return (
       <div>
          {!isNavbarHidden && <NavbarComponent />}
          { /* Your rest of the code here *//}
          {this.props.children}
       </div>
    );
}
```

I hope this helps. Cheers :)

Comment: if I want to hide on login I need to write this logic in login??and can you please help what to write in logic ?

Comment: yes you can write that in your <Login> components logic, give me a minute let me edit my answer. :)

Comment: sorry to ask but my component is rendering because I have defined it in my index.js as top because of that it is rendering it in my every page. if I have to follow your way I need to remove it from there and add everywhere how u said..right?

Comment: Oh in that case bro, just define this logic in your parent layout file, and it is the same as above.

Comment: thanks for the response..m getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentRoutes' of undefined` I defined your code in my HeaderContainer

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to mention for this you have to use a helper method given by react-router which is called withRouter, this is a small code guide which tells you on how to implement it https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154995/discussion-between-lowcool-and-adeel-imran).

Answer (score 0):

With help @Adeel's help I was ble to figure out the solution in my header container I added below code and it worked

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visibility: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
         let currentRoutes = this.props.location;


if (currentRoutes.pathname === '/' || currentRoutes.pathname === '/signUp') {

    this.setState({ visibility: false });
  }

    this.props.dispatch(fetchProgramsData());
    this.props.dispatch(fetchCompany());
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 let currentRoutes = nextProps.location;
   if (currentRoutes.pathname === '/' || currentRoutes.pathname === '/signUp') {

    this.setState({ visibility: false });
  }
  else
        this.setState({ visibility: true });

  }
```