# How to hide NavBar in login & signup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I've been searching for a while about how to hide the navigate in login and signup using react-router-dom or whatever, all what I've found is a complicated codes and very old posts and they doesn't help me. All I ask if it's possible to hide the navbar only for login & signup pages or should I put the navbar in each component I don't think that makes sense.

I have tried to do as the same of this post [How to hide navbar in login or signup page reactn router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46342711/how-to-hide-navbar-in-login-or-signup-page-reactn-router) but I'm getting undefined result for `this.props.location`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';


import Login from './login';
import signup from './signup';
import Home from './dashboard/index';
import NavBar from './navbar';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isNavbarHidden: false
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <NavBar/>
                <Router>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                            <Route path="/signup" component={signup} />
                            <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                        </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display the `<NavBar />` based on the `isNavBarHidden` state:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            { (this.state.isNavBarHidden) ? null : <NavBar /> }
            <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/signup" component={signup} />
                        <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
                    </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then set it to true when you load the `Login` component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @sme. Can you please explain to me how may I set it up to true for Login component do you mean inside the component or in this code  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

Answer (score 0):

I could not use the accepted solution as I could not find a good way to set my state to detect whether I am in login page or not. I can't use useLocation hook to detect login page, from within the same component that puts the Router into the tree.

Below is how I ended up doing this. I simply use CSS to hide the navbar element after my login component is mounted.

```
class LoginBox extends React.Component<>{

       ...

       // Hide navigation bar in login page. Do it inside ComponentDidMount as we need to wait for navbar to render before hiding it.
       componentDidMount(){
          document.getElementById('navigation-bar')!.style.display = "none";
       }

       componentWillUnmount(){
          document.getElementById('navigation-bar')!.style.display = "flex";
       }

       render(){
          return(
              // your login/signup component here
              ...
          )
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On all of your components sir declare your Navbar Component aside from the component that you dont want your navbar to show then in your App.js, you can declare the routes of application without calling the NavBar component outside the Route. You can also use Css to hide it by using props